# silent push notifications in react native app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are working on a react native app, in which we have some features where we can do some actions using silent push notifications. we are using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase.) for that.

For sending push notifications we are using firebase cloud functions, here is the payload structure.

```
 let payload = {
    token: pushToken,
    priority: normal,
    data : { 
        RequestUserID : event.params.requestId,
    }
```

We are not getting callbacks for app when its running in foreground or background ?

Any solution to get silent push notifications so that we can perform some tasks, when app is in foreground, background or killed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to not give an alert (unless the user disabled them) when the app is backgrounded or killed and receives a push notification. You could send data and run a task while the app is backgrounded if you use a websocket. That would not send an alert. If the app is closed, you won't be able to make it do any task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send you data in a `notification` payload instead of in a `data` payload. As seen in https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage